# Exclude Holidays without using a date dimension

Tags: mysql

I'm writing queries on a pre-existing mysql database. Some of those queries require me to calculate the interval between two dates without considering holidays. The problem is that my original solution (creating a date table with 40 or plus years and the flag Holiday is not feasible (as they don't let me to create another table on their database), plus I have to consider local holidays too (patrons here in Italy are holiday restricted to single towns) so with the date dimension solution i'd have to add a "Patron in" field with the name of the patron's towns each day (7000+ towns in Italy), as an added difficulty some Patrons are "floating" as "first sunday of July".
Can you think of alternate ways to achieve the objective?

Comment: you could try to retrieve the holidays from some api like `https://holidayapi.com/` but that could be a lot of querying when you cannot store those locally. (if not in a database, may be in a file?)

Comment: Can you make a temp table and use that in your join. Either way it sounds like you will have to manage holiday dates for each `patron in` to do this correctly.

Comment: Unless there is a way to calculate all the holiday dates dynamically, you need a configuration table.

Comment: What you call 'patrons', we call 'patron saints'.

Comment: There may be 7000+ towns, and 7000+ saints, but there are only 365 days.

Comment: Some days belong to more than one saint. Some saints are honoured over several consecutive days. And some saints are celebrated on different days in different places. But, by my calculation, there are only approximately 526 distinct patron saint holidays. In other words, there are only approximately 526 rules governing on which day a holiday occurs. Does that help?

Comment: I'd be a long and boring job compiling a time table with all the saints even if I could put a this table in the database.